# Django and python memcached and session engine

Tags: django, memcached

I have a question about setting cache with memcached in a django project.

in settings.py file i have:

```
CACHES = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
    'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    'TIMEOUT': 120
 }
}
```

**it works but the default session_engine in django is *django.contrib.sessions.backends.db***  but when i change the setting to ***django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache*** i have the following error:

```
 The request's session was deleted before the request completed
```

The version of django that i use is django 1.11

i searched the community about similar questions but i couldn't figure out a solution

When i use the setting : ***django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db*** it works but then again it use a table in database if i understand correctly.

Also an other error that i get is:

```
The request's session was deleted before the request completed.
The user may have logged out in a concurrent request, for example.
```

Well to answer my question (through trial and error):

From the django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/

```
Set SESSION_ENGINE to "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache" for a
simple caching session store. Session data will be stored directly in your    
cache. However, session data may not be persistent: cached data can be 
 evicted if the cache fills up or if the cache server is restarted.

For persistent, cached data, set SESSION_ENGINE to 
"django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db". This uses a write-through 
cache – every write to the cache will also be written to the database.
Session reads only use the database if the data is not already in the    
cache.
```

so the final settings for memcached that i use:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db"
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS = "default"

CACHES = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
    'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    'TIMEOUT': 120
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the memcached service isn't started so your sessions that you are attempting to store in the cache are not persisting. You'll want to make sure you have the memcached service started.

```
sudo apt-get -y install memcached
sudo service memcached restart
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: When do you get this error? Have you tried to remove the timeout setting to ensure the session isn't removed from the cache due to that?

Comment: even though i disabled the timeout i get the error : The request's session was deleted before the request completed. The user may have logged out in a concurrent request, for example.